# How can I find a <ul> elements from dropdown in a page using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, visual-studio-code

```
<ul _ngcontent-c9 class="results-dropdown">
 <li _ngcontent-c9>
  <a _ngcontent-c9>XYZ</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to find XYZ value from dropdown and click on it.

Please let me know if anyone is having guideline for the same.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

```
var dropdown = element(by.css('ul'));
var dropdownValues = element(by.css('ul > li > a'));
var expectedText = 'XYZ';

dropdown.click();
return dropdownValues.filter((eachValue) => {
    return eachValue.getText().then((valueText) => {
        if (valueText === expectedText) {
            return eachValue.click();
        }
    });
});
```

or

```
var dropdown = element(by.css('ul'));
var expectedText = 'XYZ';

dropdown.click();
element(by.linkText(expectedText)).click();
```